# How do I "ping" a different domain to check reachability (within Windows Server)?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003

I'm troubleshooting a connectivity issue between servers on different domains.

I have a Web Service installed on **DOMAIN01\SERVER1**. This WebService uses Windows Authentication as its authentication mechanism.

Right now, the Web Service is setup to use **DOMAIN01\SOME_USER** as the only user allowed.

The clients who will connect to this Web Service are on **DOMAIN02** and they've requested that the user allowed on the service should be **DOMAIN02\OTHER_USER**.

Whatever the user is, I need to give permission on the service's root folder to him. So, I went into the security properties of the folder and tried browsing Active Directory, but **DOMAIN02** isn't listed. Hence, not allowing me to set permissions.

Given that the domain isn't listed, is it safe to assume that the domain is not accessible from that server?

Is there a way to check whether the domain is "reachable"?

And is there a way to set permissions correctly without being able to browse through active directory?

Ps.: I'm using "domain" terminology here but, to be honest, I'm not sure wheter those are actual domains os subdomains. Does it make any difference?

Comment: You need to create a Forest trust between the two domains to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there is no trust between Domain01 and Domain02.  To have Domain02 users available to assign rights in the file system of a server within Domain01, then you have to have Domain01 trust Domain02, one way, at minimum.  See [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773178(v=ws.10).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Forest Trust will enable Domain02 users to access resources on Domain01.  When it comes to ping, you have to use software or hardware router.

For software router you can use RRAS (Routing and Remote Access).  RRAS is available in Windows Server 2003.  You need 2 LAN cards to establish connections between 2 domains.

Comment: Your comments regarding the network connection are valid if the domains are physically separated or not on the same physical network.  The networking gurus can set up VLANs and routing between them if they are on the same physical network.  Network gurus are the ones to help with WAN routing as well.